# Trying to run epub.js on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, epub, epub.js

Hi i'm trying to run epub.js on ie...

- I've tried all tipps in the documents
- I've fixed the examples/ie.html so it runs on FF.. but IE still shows noting
- i don't get any javascript errors with the hooks, but an empty page (already tried different epubs)

Can anyone point me to a working example of epub.js which is actually running on IE11?

Or is IE definitely not supported?

What makes me wonder because there are tipps on the homepage how to make it run on IE ... but not one working example.

Comment: are you using 'wgxpath'? is it working on other IE versions?

Comment: yes... otherwise i get JS errors